# Android - Espresso - longClick is (still) available?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

My first impression is that Espresso helps tremenduously in automatic testing of Android Apps. Great! Thank you Google (employees).

What about the `longClick()` - is it still available as an `ViewAction`?

```
button1 = onView( withId( R.id.buttonOK)); 
button1.perform( click());
```

Works fine, but I cannot use the `longClick` or `doubleClick` in the perform. It seems not available. Why? 
All other `ViewActions` can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Yashodhan:

Just use this *special* kind of import:

```
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions.longClick;
```

Yes, and it works! And the tests all went well.